# Google Shopping API - Replacements?

Tags: api, search, google-shopping-api

I have an app which uses the Google Shopping API which is unfortunately being pulled very shortly.

I am having real difficulties finding a good replacement which will give me varied product search results with an image, price and supplier.  I have explored Semantics3 which seems a relatively good alternative but doesn't produce many UK results. Ideally I am looking for something which will produce both UK & US results..

I was interested in what alternatives others are looking at...?

Thanks :-)

Comment: The Semantics3 Product API (https://semantics3.com/) is a direct replacement. http://shoppingapishutdown.com Disclosure: I am one of the co-founders :)

Comment: Thanks - is there an email address I can message you on please? @netvarun

Answer (score 0):

in our app, we use 3 search engines: Google Shopping API, Google Custom Search API, and Shopping.com Search API (owned by Ebay). I'm currently in wait-and-see if Google really does  terminate the Shopping API on 16 Sep; hopefully not.

You can try to shopping.com API, both US and UK markets . the API is using XML. 
http://developer.shopping.com/docs/read/API_Use_Cases#22

Answer (score 0):

I'm representative of https://aerse.com. Aerse provides:

- Free access using API
- Clear product names and specifications
- Good search algorithms: "product name" + "one of the product's property name", "vendor name" + "property value" and etc.

Comment: The problem with aerse.com is that there is almost no relevant product data on it.  A search for iPad returned nothing.

Comment: It's designed to return exact matches. Since "iPad" is ambiguous query - Aerse will return nothing. However Aerse has "Aerse PRO" where you could execute queries by properties. For example: "type -> tablet, series -> iPad". In that case Aerse will return all first generation iPads. Or you could execute search by EAN/UPC: https://aerse.com/f?r=0885909550746

Comment: I also registered for an Aerse key, but none of the products I am interested in are in Aerse`s database (mostly photography and video production related equipment, like cameras, lighting equipment, monitors, lenses, lenses filters, and so on). Example of UPC code: 049383047097 (Tiffen 67mm Neutral Density, 0.6 filter).